# Later implementing inapp purchase for free app android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I want to publish an android app which is free on download but can be upgraded using in app purchase. Right not I want to keep all functionality intact in the paid version and implement inapp purchase  and disable full functionality later when releasing a new update.

Is this possible to do such a thing because on the developers console it says that"Setting the price to 'Free' is permanent. You cannot change it back to 'Paid' again after publishing"

Or should I follow the first few steps of implementing inapp purchases like adding permissions,aidl files etc.,then release the free app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This term is only about the initial prize of the app.
In app purchases are totally independent of that.

**Yep you can add in-app purchases later** altough your app is free without problems.